# Populating custom field with lookup parent ID

Tags: apex

I want to populate a custom text field with the ID of the parent record chosen in another lookup field. What is the best approach towards implementing this? Is trigger the only way with this, or is a non programatic method available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are Text field and lookup field on the same object?

Comment: @AnitaBhanarkar Yes they are

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula field instead of text if possible. No need to write trigger.

Comment: I am planning to use the field for matching rules, thanks for the suggestion though.